# Unable to Install software-center

Tags: software-installation

```
Reading package lists...Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information...Done
Package software-Center is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only avaliable from another source 

E: Package 'software-Center' has no installation candidate
```

Is this any solution to this error? 
I currently have no internet browser and this error is the same with say "Google-chrome"

Comment: What distribution and version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

The package name is case-sensitive: you need to run

```
sudo apt-get install sofware-center
```

all in lower case.

As far as Chrome is concerned, you can either install Chromium from the Ubuntu repositories (where it's called `chromium-browser`) or download Chrome from [Google](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html).